# HTTP Get not using Port

Tags: http, http-headers, apache2, neolane

I am trying to call a page in PHP with a http_get :

```
$url = "http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=1135446";
http_get($url, $appelOptions, $appelInfos);
```

My problem is that it does not work every time.

I installed Wireshark to see what I'm really sending and I found an odd thing. Sometimes, the port is not used for the HTTP request.

When it works, I have :

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=1135446 HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Request Method: GET
    Request URI: http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=1135446
    Request Version: HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PECL::HTTP/1.6.5 (PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7)\r\n
Host: mysite.fr:9090\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Keep-Alive: 300\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 16:40:46 +0200\r\n
Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.5\r\n
\r\n
```

And when it's not :

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
GET http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=1135446 HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Request Method: GET
    Request URI: http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=1135446
    Request Version: HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PECL::HTTP/1.6.5 (PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7)\r\n
Host: mysite.fr\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Keep-Alive: 300\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 16:40:34 +0200\r\n
Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.5\r\n
\r\n
```

I tried to call the page with wget and it's always working :

```
wget http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=1135446
```

So I'm guessing that my problem id due to Apache config, but I don't know where to look. Could you help me please ?

Comment: $appelOptions = Array (
    [url] => http://mysite.fr:9090/neolane-webservice/campagnesclient/Coclico=724098
    [compress] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Keep-Alive] => 300
            [Connection] => keep-alive
            [Date] => Mon, 18 Jun 2012 16:47:54 +0200
            [Accept-Charset] => utf-8
        )

    [timeout] => 10
    [proxyhost] => http://myproxy
);

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the port in the `$appelOptions` array.

```
$appelOptions['port']=9090;
http_get($url, $appelOptions, $appelInfos);
```

Unfortunately `http_get` does not seem to respect the :port syntax in the URL